# Can the text on the transparent object (alpha blend ) be completely opaque in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I'm stuck in a project with a client and I'm trying to create a box that should be transparent and have salt in it, but I also want the text on the box to be completely opaque.

That is what I have achieved on my own:

[image: This is what I have achieved on my own]

I would like to achieve that the black text is displayed opaque:

[image: I would like to achieve that the black text is displayed opaque]

This is the node structure I have, the PSD file is the text with white background in image texture:

[image: This is the node structure i have, The PSD file is the text with white background in image texture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Mix Shader* to mix the glass material (with *Transmission* at 1) with the text material (with *Transmission* at 0 and whatever settings you want for this part), and use the alpha channel of the text image as factor, something like that:

[image]

In Eevee don't forget to enable the various settings in the Material panel: Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend and *Screen Space Refraction*, disable *Show Backface*, and in the *Render* panel enable *Screen Space Reflections* and then *Refraction*.

Comment: I did it , changed the blend mode to Alpha blende , same issue , I am working on eevee

Comment: check my edit, if the result is still bad, use another thing than Transmission and Glass, for example try a mix between Transparent, Glossy and Diffuse, etc